# calculate average time based on cell value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, grouping

Ok this is pretty simple but i'm drawing a blank and can't even think on the right combination of words to search for the answer.

I have a tsql table with start and end time, task, as well as a new/repeat flag.

I want to pull the average duration between start and end, both when the record is new and when it is a repeat.  I'll be grouping on the task.

My result would look like Task - NewDurationAverage - RepeatDurationAverage.

Cheers in advance.

Comment: what efforts did you put till now ??

Comment: I've tried a NewAvg = Case type = 'new' then avg(duration) end, RepAvg = Case type = 'Repeat' then avg(duration) end, and grouped, and then had to group again.. Not sure if it's working righ though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be something like this:

```
SELECT TaskId, NewDurationAverage, RepeatDurationAverage FROM

(SELECT TaskId, DATEDIFF(hh, TaskStart, TaskEnd) as NewDurationAverage 
  FROM Task WHERE IsNew=1 GROUP BY TaskId) NewTasks

LEFT OUTER JOIN

(SELECT TaskId, DATEDIFF(hh, TaskStart, TaskEnd) as RepeatDurationAverage
  FROM Task WHERE IsRepeat=1 GROUP BY TaskId) RepeatTasks

ON NewTasks.TaskId=RepeatTasks.TaskId
```

Comment: Yes.  Thankyou.  I was tired and knew this was a simple solution.  Cheers for your guidance

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the steps below:

1. Find the difference between the `start` and the `end` date/time columns. For example, using [DATEDIFF](https://www.google.bg/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=t%20sql%20datediff) function
2. Perform the `AVG` on the calculated value
3. Convert the result in any appropriate format you want

Depending on your needs, you can make `DATEDIFF` to return the time difference in a desire format (days, minutes, nanoseconds, etc). So, have to decided how precise the results should be (smaller is better).